# Is there any way to convert list object to json key value pair in java?

Tags: java, json, list

i have list that have some values and i need to convert them into json object like first value in list as key in json and others as value in json. is this possible?

I have the below value as list object :

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList();
list = [s.no-name-type, 1-what is your name-text, 2-what is your name-text, 3-what is your role?-text, 4-Tell us something to improve ourselves.!-text];
```

is there anyone can we convert those list object into JSON like
`list[0]` as `key` and others as values in java springboot?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand correctly, but supposing you have the following class:

```
class MyObject {
    private final String key;
    private final List<String> values;

    public MyObject(String key, List<String> values) {
        this.key = key;
        this.values = values;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public List<String> getValues() {
        return values;
    }
}
```

You can convert your list with:

```
new MyObject(list.get(0), list.subList(1, list.size()));
```

You can then use your favorite JSON library to convert this object to JSON.